# jplayer - not enough arguments

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jplayer

this question concerns the jplayer plugin for wp-ecommerce (http://getshopped.org/premium-upgrades/premium-plugin/jplayer-mp3-player/) and has two parts. I asked the question on their forums, but although it´s a paid plugin they don´t provide nearly any support...

So part one: i use the jplayer plugin to preview mp3s (example http://www.bombthebass.com/store/music/x-ray-eyes/) Whenever an mp3 is played, console in chrome returns an Uncaught TypeError: Not enough arguments on line 34 of jquery.jplayer.js.min. Can anybody figure out where it´s coming from?

Part two: In general i try to get the player to pause all other instances when one instance ist started. This doesn´t work with a fresh install (shouldn´t it be default behavior?)
I tried to manually add jplayers pauseOthers Method like this:

$('#jquery_jplayer_').bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() {         $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});

This returns an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined.
As it´s a plugin for wordpress all necessary scripts should be included. I also tried older versions of jquery (current 1.7.1, older one i tried werde 1.4 & 1.6). Why is the play event undefined?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok for everybody that wants to know: there was a compatibility issue with the wpsc jplayer script and recent versions of jquery, whis is now fixed in the current plugin version.